# How can I target a test in the _before() hook

Tags: codeception

I have a Codeception cest file which has a number of tests in it.

In some of the tests, there are *initializations* which I would like to so in the `_before()` hook. These *initializations* are specific to those tests only and to no other test in the cest file.

How can I go about this?

The pseudocode would be something like

```
public _before($event)
{
  if ($event->test_being_run == 'testThatFeature')
  {
    $init = something(here);
  }
}
```

Through investigation, I have realized that the `$event` variable passed into the `_before()` hook is an instance of the generated `AcceptanceTester`; as opposed to `\Codeception\Event\TestCase`. So I cannot use the hopeful `$event->getTest()->getTestFullName()`.

Answer (score 0):

Codeception injects parameters based on type hinting.

If you want to get \Codeception\Event\TestCase, your code must look like this:

`public _before(\Codeception\Event\TestCase $event)`

Comment: if I prefix the className to that variable, it causes my test to fail with   `[yii\base\ErrorException] Argument 1 passed to tests\codeception\frontend\acceptance\ABCest::_before() must be an instance of tests\codeception\frontend\acceptance\Codeception\Event\TestEvent, instance of tests\codeception\frontend\AcceptanceTester given`

Comment: It still uses the generated `AcceptanceTester`. Now we just give PHP a reason to complain because it's expecting something else.

Answer (score 0):

All information that I found about receiving testcase in _before method, was about _before method of modules and extensions, it does not apply to tests.

If you want to run specific code for one test, just run it in the test code.